# Android, upgraded existing project to sdk2.3, now get null pointer

Tags: android, build, sdk

I upgraded to the 2.3 sdk today, and then changed my project build target to 2.3 and did a clean and build. When I run it on a 2.2 device I get a null pointer exception on this line:

```
mSoundPool.play(index, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, speed);
```

Which worked fine with the 2.2 sdk, is the something I'm doing wrong or not doing that I need to in order to properly upgrade my project's build target?

This is how it's initialized:

```
mSoundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that a full clean build fixed the problem. Its a bit sketchy since I had cleaned the build once already, the second time fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that mSoundPool object is null, so we'd need to see how you construct it.

Comment: Added the initialization line above. Note, that this code all works fine on 2.2 sdk.